# Closing an io.Reader that might be an os.Stdin

Tags: go

I am trying to set a file as input if a file name is given or use standard input if no file name is given. I would have thought that this is the way to do so:

```golang
var input io.Reader
if filename == "" {
  input = os.Stdin
} else {
  input, err = os.Open(filename)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to open file: %v", err)
  }
}
```

The function that is passed `input` expects something that conforms to the `io.Reader` interface and all behaves well. That is the above works ...

It works until I try to figure out a way to close `input`. Although both things returned by os.Stdin and os.Open (sure, closing stdin might not really mean much, but it is harmless). The compiler doesn't know that both ways of creating `input` give me something that implements Close(). So I was wondering there there is a way to tell the compiler that `Close()` is implemented for `input`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [io.ReadCloser](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadCloser) to declare that `input` has Read and Close methods:

```
var input io.ReadCloser
if filename == "" {
  input = os.Stdin
} else {
  input, err = os.Open(filename)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to open file: %v", err)
  }
}
```

If the file is closed just before return from the function, then another option is to defer the file close:

```
var input io.Reader
if filename == "" {
  input = os.Stdin
} else {
  f, err := os.Open(filename)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to open file: %v", err)
  }
  defer f.Close()
  input = f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in the course of writing up my question for others and working to spell things out, I realized that declaring input with

```golang
var input *os.File
```

fixes everything.

I have failed to look at the type of `os.Stdin` until I started to write up the question. And so I declared `input` in terms of the most general interface required by the function that will use it.

Answer (score -1):

The way to check if an `io.Reader` implements `Close` is to use type assertion as:

```
if closer, ok:=reader.(io.Closer); ok {
   err:=closer.Close()
}
```

Comment: That tells you whether the `io.Reader` implements `io.Closer`, but that doesn't tell you who is responsible for actually calling the `Close` method — and `io.Closer` leaves the behavior of doubled calls to `Close` explicitly undefined. So that type-assertion is, at best, fragile and dangerous.